# Div within div won't become full width

Tags: css, html, width

I have a div `#description` inside another div `.item`, which I want to have the same width as the div it is in. This is the div:

```
<div class="item">
    <div id="description">
        <h2>Title</h2>
        <p>Description</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

So, `#description` has to have the same width as `.item`. The problem is that `#description` does not respond to the CSS I wrote, even when I use different percentages. My guess that it stops filling horizontally at around `30%`, instead of `100%`.

```
.item {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid;
    border-color:  #575757;
    position: relative;
}

#description {
    width: 100%;
    height: 40%;
    bottom: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: whitesmoke;
    color: #000000;
}
```

To my knowledge, the inner div should automatically become the same width as the outer without specifying any width properties, right? So why is this not working?

Comment: item is floating and description is positioned absolute, so item has no width since it is floating. floating elements has no width if there is no content. even setting it to 100%, it has no height because your content is absolute. Remove ablsute position and you get http://jsfiddle.net/k37qs/

Answer (score 2):

When an element is absolutely positioned, it is essentially [removed from the natural document flow](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html). In this case, the parent element `.item`, no longer has dimensions because the child element is no longer in the flow. The element `.item` essentially collapses upon itself, therefore causing the children elements to do the same. In order to solve this, you would either need to remove the absolute positioning, or you would need to set defined dimensions on the parent element.

Here is an example setting a height of `200px` on the parent element - [(example)](http://jsfiddle.net/kqEwG/). This may work in certain circumstances, but it isn't really ideal because it won't work with dynamic content.

As an alternative, you could remove the absolute positioning and the child element `.description` will automatically take the dimensions of the parent. [(example)](http://jsfiddle.net/WenSK/1/) This is *basically* default behavior of `block` level elements given that certain properties are reset from their browser defaults.

Comment: Even without the absolute positioning and the floating the description won't fill the width of item.

Comment: @Tomjesch Did you look at the example I provided? Given that it is the only child element, it will fill the parent.

Comment: I did, both actually. Like you said, I prefer the second example (if it was working) because it would automatically take the dimensions of item. Currently looking through the W3 formatting model, maybe that clears things up...

Comment: Even your second example does not generate the desired result.

Comment: @Tomjesch I must not understand what your desired result is then. The child element `.description` does take the full width of the parent. http://i.stack.imgur.com/X8q5p.png .. If you were to give `.description` a red background, it would cover the entire element http://jsfiddle.net/WenSK/2/ .. is this not what you want?

Comment: Thats exactly what I want! I currently use 'whitesmoke' as background-color, but that shouldn't make any difference.